# Using a different ordering on lists

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, the default ordering for [a], given an ordering on a, seems to be a lexicographic ordering (side question: where can I find out if this is really the case)? What I want is a graded lexicographic ordering (also called "length plus lexicographic" ordering).

How would I specify that I want comparisons to be done in a graded lexicographical manner? I want it for only one type, not for all [a]. I tried this:

```
instance Ord [Int] where
  compare xs ys = case compare (length xs) (length ys) of
                          LT -> LT
                          GT -> GT
                          EQ -> lexicographic_compare xs ys
```

but got this error message:

```
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
test.hs:1:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `Ord [Int]'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `Ord [Int]'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Have you tried adding `-XFlexibleInstances` to the GHC arguments, as the error suggests?

Comment: @RobinGreen: that wouldn't help since there is obviously already a conflicting `Ord [Int]` instance, the defaul lexicographical one.

Comment: Robin Green, thank you for your suggestions. I have not tried that, how do I add this option?

Comment: @Calle: to switch on such extensions, put `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` on top of your source file. But again, this wouldn't help in your case.

Comment: From the Haskell Report: "Instances of `Ord` can be derived for any user-defined datatype whose constituent types are in `Ord`. The declared order of the constructors in the data declaration determines the ordering in derived `Ord` instances." and "`data  [a]  =  [] | a : [a]  deriving (Eq, Ord)`" together mean that yes, it's lexicographic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a typical application for a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype GradedLexOrd a = GradedLexOrd { runGradedLexOrd :: [a] }

instance (Ord a) => Ord (GradedLexOrd a) where
  compare (GradedLexOrd xs) (GradedLexOrd ys) = gradedLexOrd xs ys

gradedLexOrd :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
gradedLexOrd = comparing length <> compare -- Nice Monoid-based implementation,
                                           --due to Aaron Roth (see answer below)
```

Alternatively, you could openly use lists, but instead of the `Ord` constrained functions like `sort` use the more general alternatives which accept a custom comparison function, e.g. `sortBy gradedLexOrd`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two questions here:

### How does `Ord [a]` looks like?

Of course you can experiment within `GHCi`, but maybe you want something more reliable. This is surprisingly difficult, especially as the definition of Lists is (due to their special syntax) built into the compiler. Let’s ask GHCi:

```
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
instance Eq a => Eq [a] -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Monad [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Ord a => Ord [a] -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Read a => Read [a] -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance Show a => Show [a] -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
```

It says that the instance is defined in `GHC.Classes`, which [we find in GHC’s git repo](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc-prim/GHC/Classes.hs#L184), and there it says:

```
instance (Ord a) => Ord [a] where
        {-# SPECIALISE instance Ord [Char] #-}
        compare []     []     = EQ
        compare []     (_:_)  = LT
        compare (_:_)  []     = GT
        compare (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of
                                    EQ    -> compare xs ys
                                    other -> other
```

So yes, it is indeed the lexicographic ordering.

### How to overwrite the ordering?

Don’t. There is an instance for `[a]` and there can be only one. With `FlexibleInstances` and `OverlappingInstances`, you could make it use an alternative instance for, say, `[Int]`, but it is bad style. As leftaroundabout writes, use a `NewtypeWrapper` for it, or use parametrized functions like `sortBy`.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a whole new `Ord` instance for lists of `Int`s seems a bit heavyweight to my taste (not to mention that you may be sowing confusion: someone who comes along to your code later will probably expect the default, non-graded lexicographic comparison behavior).

If you're merely hoping not to have to copy your custom comparison code every time you use `sortBy` or the like, there's actually a fairly lightweight way of defining chained comparison functions like yours on the spot. `Ordering`, as it happens, is an instance of `Monoid`, which means you can compare two things according to a succession of criteria, then combine the resulting `Ordering`s of those comparisons using the `Monoid` function, `mappend` (recently abbreviated to `<>`). This is all explained in some detail in the [Learn You a Haskell chapter on Monoids, etc.](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids), which is where I picked up the trick. So:

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Ord (comparing)

gradedLexicographicCompare :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
gradedLexicographicCompare xs ys = comparing length xs ys <> comparing id xs ys
```

(Of course, `comparing id` is just `compare`, but for the sake of uniformity...) Then it becomes relatively unburdensome to write things like

```
f = ... sortBy s ...
  where
    ...
    s xs ys = comparing length xs ys <> compare xs ys
    ...
```

And this also has the virtue that your successor will see immediately that you're using a custom comparison function.

**Update**: leftaroundabout points out below that we can achieve even greater elegance -- this is Haskell after all, and in Haskell we can always achieve greater elegance -- by making use of the monoid instance, `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)`. That is, a function whose result is a monoid can itself be considered a monoid. The instance is given by

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
  mempty _ = mempty
  mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x   (1)
```

Now let's indulge in a little equational reasoning and see what `comparing length <> compare` expands to according to this instance. Applying (1) once, we have

```
comparing length <> compare
    = mappend (comparing length) compare
    = \xs -> mappend ((comparing length) xs) (compare xs)   (2)
```

But `((comparing length) xs) :: [a] -> Ordering` and `(compare xs) :: (Ord a) => a -> Ordering` are themselves functions whose results are monoids, namely `Ordering`s, so we can apply (1) a second time to obtain

```
mappend ((comparing length) xs) (compare xs)
    = \ys -> mappend (((comparing length) xs) ys) ((compare xs) ys)   (3)
```

But now `(((comparing length) xs) ys)` and `((compare xs) ys)` are fully applied functions. Specifically, they are `Ordering`s, and from the original answer we know how to combine two `Ordering`s using `mappend` from the **`Ordering`** instance of `Monoid`. (Note that we are *not* using `mappend` from (1).) Writing everything down in one big chain, we have

```
comparing length <> compare
    = mappend (comparing length) compare   [definition of <>]
    = \xs -> mappend ((comparing length) xs) (compare xs)   [by (1)]
    = \xs -> (\ys -> mappend (((comparing length) xs) ys) ((compare xs) ys))   [substituting (3) in (2)]
    = \xs -> \ys -> mappend (comparing length xs ys) (compare xs ys)   [function application is left associative]
    = \xs -> \ys -> comparing length xs ys <> compare xs ys   [definition of <>]
```

And the last line of this expansion is just our original `gradedLexicographicCompare`! After a long, long digression, then, the punchline is that we can write the elegantly points-free

```
gradedLexicographicCompare = comparing length <> compare
```

Pretty.

Comment: +1 for using the nice Monoid thing -- by coincidence, I recently stumpled upon the Monoid instance of Ordering and wondered what this was good for - now I know.

Comment: This is _really_ nice, because there's also the `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a->b)`. So you can in fact write simply `sortBy (comparing length <> compare)`: both arguments of each comparison are automatically "pulled in" by the function monoid instance.